# Automatic height of ViewCell in Xamarin Forms on iOS with ViewCellRenderer

Tags: ios, forms, listview, xamarin

For performance reasons I decided to write a custom ViewCell for my ListView in Xamarin Forms. For this ViewCell I've extended the ViewCellRenderer for iOS. In the GetCell-Method I create a new instance of an extended UITableViewCell which creates some labels and images and arranges them by some constraints on the anchors.

The ListView in Xamarin Forms has HasUnevenRows="True", but the rows are all cut-off at 44px. How can I get automatic height to the rows by the created content from the custom UITableViewCell?

Comment: Have you solved your problem or tried my solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Cause:**

Actually, The auto height with `HasUnevenRows=true` works fine on iOS if **not using** a custom renderer.

If using a custom renderer, then it is **up to the renderer to set the height of the cell**, but in reality you have to do it in the **GetHeightForRow** override of the **UITableViewSource**.

This means you have to calculate the row height in `UITableViewSource` that you make that sets the height for a row in the `GetHeightForRows` `override` if you want to use custom viewcell render in the listView with uneven rows.

**Solution:**

Basically you have to make a  custom `ListView renderer`. Then you have to get the `UITableView's` Source property  (Control.Source in the list view renderer) and pass that to a new instance of a subclass of `UITableVIewSource` that you create, and then override all of the `UITableViewSource` methods so you can call into the original source methods when you don't want to change anything, but for the **GetRowForHeight** method, you would return the height you want for that row. E.G.:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(ListView), typeof(MyLVRenderer))]
public class MyLVRenderer : ListViewRenderer
    {
        //UITableViewSource originalSource;

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<ListView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            UITableViewSource originalSource = (UIKit.UITableViewSource)Control.Source;
            Control.Source = new MyLVSource(originalSource);

        }
    }

    public class MyLVSource : UITableViewSource
    {
        UITableViewSource originalSource;

        public MyLVSource(UITableViewSource origSource)
        {
            originalSource = origSource;
        }

        public override nint RowsInSection(UITableView tableview, nint section)
        {
            return originalSource.RowsInSection(tableview, section);
        }

        public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            return originalSource.GetCell(tableView, indexPath);
        }

        public override nfloat GetHeightForFooter(UITableView tableView, nint section)
        {
            return originalSource.GetHeightForFooter(tableView, section);
        }

        public override nfloat GetHeightForRow(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            nfloat origHeight = originalSource.GetHeightForRow(tableView, indexPath);

            // calculate your own row height here
            return origHeight + (indexPath.Row +1) * 10;
        }                
    }
```

This is a example of increasing the row height by ten for every row. You have to calculate your own row height by yourself. I can share you the demo if you need.

Refer: [viewcell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/viewcell)

Comment: Perfect - that's it!

Answer (score 0):

You should override `LayoutSubviews`. You should set `renderer.NativeView.Frame` to proper values.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! What exactly is `renderer`? I've tried several approaches in `LayoutSubviews`:

1. `this.Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(...)`
2. `this.ViewCell.Height = ...`
3. `this.ContentView.Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(...)`

all with and without `this.ViewCell.ForceUpdateSize()` - no chance of setting the height manually.

Comment: You need to look how Xamarin does it, the critical part is in that line, https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS/Cells/ViewCellRenderer.cs

Comment: Mh, the problem is that in my case `ViewCell.View` is `null` and therefore a renderer can't be created.

Comment: Do you have any idea?